# How to execute a windows batch command recursively?

Tags: windows, shell, command-line, batch-file, cmd

For example, you have a rename command in a batch file, and you want to execute that file on the current directory and all sub-directories.

Comment: do you have a concrete example?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25381530/99777

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Batch File Looping Through Directories to Process Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397674/windows-batch-file-looping-through-directories-to-process-files)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Suppose your batch is named something like `myrename.cmd`, then you can easily do the following:

```
call myrename.cmd
for /r /d %%x in (*) do (
    pushd "%%x"
    call myrename.cmd
    popd
)
```

The first line will run it for the current directory, the `for` loop will iterate recursively (`/r`) over all directories (`/d`) and execute the part in the parentheses. What we do inside them is change the directory to the one we're currently iterating over with `pushd`—which has the nice property that you can undo that directory change with `popd`—and then run the command, which then will be run in the directory we just switched to.

This assumes that the batch lies somewhere in the path. If it doesn't and just happens to lie where the batch file above lies, then you can use

```
"%~dp0myrename.cmd"
```

Comment: What does the last bit mean?

Comment: @VirgilIerubino: What last bit? The part with `%~dp0`? See `help for` for an explanation.