# Copy Files recursively from inside directory to outside using batch file

Tags: recursion, batch-file, xcopy

There is this directory structure:

```
Dir1
--Dir2
    --File1
    --File2
--Dir3
    --File3
--File4
--File5
```

Now I want to copy all the files in subdirectory (Dir2, Dir3) to parent Directory Dir1 using batch files.
I have come up with the below code but it doesn't work perfectly. I get the below output -

```
Directory2             --It has 4 files all together
Invalid number of parameters
Invalid number of parameters
Does E:\Directory1\Copy\File1.dat specify a file name   -- And only this file gets copied
or directory name on the target
(F = file, D = directory)?
```

Code -

```
@echo off
call :treeProcess
Pause
goto :eof

:treeProcess
rem Do whatever you want here over the files of this subdir, for example:
for /D %%d in (*) do (
    echo %%d
    cd %%d
    for %%f in (*) do xcopy %%f E:\Movies\Copy\%%f
    call :treeProcess
    cd ..
)
exit /b
```

Comment: I mostly use one line command for this...
Dir1>XCOPY  * . * /s  Dir1

Comment: I guess you used this https://stackoverflow.com/a/8398621 as your starting point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need for a batch file. Execute the following command from your Dir1 folder:

```
for /r /d %F in (*) do @copy /y "%F\*"
```

As a batch file

```
@echo off
for /r /d %%F in (*) do copy /y "%%F\*"
```

BUT - Be aware that you may have the same file name in multiple child folders. Only one will survive in your Dir1.

**EDIT**

The above assumes you are running the command, (or the script) from the Dir1 folder. It can be run from anywhere if the script is augmented to include the path to Dir1.

```
for /r "pathToDir1" /d %F in (*) do @copy /y "pathToDir1\%F\*"
```

or as a batch file

```
@echo off
set "root=pathToDir1"
for /r "%root%" /d %%F in (*) do copy /y "%root%\%%F\*"
```

You could pass the path to Dir1 as an argument to the batch file. Pass in `.` as the path if you want to use the current folder.

```
@echo off
for /r %1 /d %%F in (*) do copy /y "%~1\%%F\*"
```

Comment: If there are no duplicates in any of the child folders then will this command copy all files from each child folder to a different folder? Also the destination is itself a child folder so I guess I should move this to a new place, i guess?

Comment: @Priyam - Yes, it copies the files to the current directory, (I'm assuming it is Dir1). You are fine as long as your source folders are children of Dir1. See my updated answer.