# Generating C# classes from XSD (VS2013 Pro)

Tags: class, xsd, visual-studio-2013

OK, so I have returned somewhat to C# development this year after spending some years in the wilderness of Java development in Netbeans.  One great tool I come across was JAXB which allows you to easily generate classes from a schema (XSD) definition.

Now I am aware there is an XSD.exe generator that I have used previously - after all that's how I found the JAXB in Netbeans - looking for the alternative.

With JAXB, all I had to do was import all the schema files into the Project within Netbeans and click on Compile.  The result - a set of compiled classes to use.

XSD has been around a lot of years now - and we are now at the end of 2013.

I have not been able to hunt down as yet anything like the JAXB equivalent for Visual Studio.
**Does such a simple tool exist where I do not need to mess around with any build configuration - so it will just compile and give me my classes?**

Given that I will probably have to generate the classes automatically, what do people recommend for doing this?

At present, I just create my solution and projects from Visual Studio.  In the past I might have added some command utils to the Pre-build command line.

**Would the following link still be the best offering these days to do this?**

[Automate XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897750/automate-xsd-exe-during-build)

This uses a batch file with the following pre-build task:

```
call "$(ProjectDir)"XSDBuilder.bat "$(ProjectDir)"\XSDs "$(Registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\@InstallationFolder)bin\xsd.exe"
```

How will this affect things with Server builds - especially hosted on Visual Studio TFS?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/943242d1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Hi Hans, I just wanted to know how to best manage this process when a solution is worked on by a number of users.  I also have it hosted on visualstudio.com.  I was wanting to set some builds up in the cloud.  I've updated the question to reflect this.