# Transfer to FTP file by file in windows batch script

Tags: batch-file, ftp

unable to transfer file by file  to ftp. please kindly advise. appreciate the help

test.ftp

```
    open ftp2.xxx.com
    xxx
    xxxxx
```

below is the .bat

```
set "ftptarget=ftp://ftp2.xxx.com/"
ftp -i -s:test.ftp

for /f "delims=" %%A in ('findstr /s /m /l /c:"100000" "%source%\*"') do (copy /y "%%A" "%ftptarget%")
```

Comment: What's wrong? Any error message? Show us the script output.

Comment: its showing ftp> in cmd

Comment: First, build the ENTIRE ftp-script, then run `ftp`, for example: [FTP directory Upload](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28778802)

Comment: Did you mean that you want to upload all files in directory one by one to your FTP sever ?

Comment: @william123456 are you some how thinking your batch file can interact with the FTP session?

Comment: Are you remembering to end your ftp script with `bye`?

Comment: Again, show us the script output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted an article many ages ago which does (I think) exactly what you want:
http://www.howtogeek.com/50359/upload-files-to-an-ftp-site-via-a-batch-script/

This script takes in a file name as a parameter or you can specify a text file which contains a listing of files to upload. The latter option can be useful if you need to upload files matching a certain criteria (just write `DIR` output to a text file and supply the text file as the parameter).

If nothing else, it should provide a working example of how to use the built in FTP command.

Here is the script from the link above:

```
@ECHO OFF
REM Usage -- save this script as "UploadToFTP.bat":
REM UploadToFTP [/L] FileToUpload
REM
REM Required Parameters:
REM  FileToUpload
REM      The file or a text file containing the list of files to be uploaded.
REM
REM Optional Parameters:
REM  /L  When supplied, the FileToUpload is read as a list of files to be uploaded.
REM      A list of files should be a plain text file which has a single file on each line.
REM      Files listed in this file must specify the full path.

SETLOCAL EnableExtensions

REM Connection information:
SET Server=
SET UserName=
SET Password=

REM ---- Do not modify anything below this line ----

SET Commands="%TEMP%SendToFTP_commands.txt"

REM FTP user name and password. No spaces after either.
ECHO %UserName%> %Commands%
ECHO %Password%>> %Commands%

REM FTP transfer settings.
ECHO binary >> %Commands%

IF /I "%~1"=="/L" (
   REM Add file(s) to the list to be FTP'ed.
   FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%I IN ("%~dpnx2") DO ECHO put "%%~I" >> %Commands%
) ELSE (
   ECHO put "%~dpnx1" >> %Commands%
)

REM Close the FTP connection.
ECHO close  >> %Commands%
ECHO bye    >> %Commands%

REM Perform the FTP.
FTP -d -i -s:%Commands% %Server%

ECHO.
ECHO.

REM Clean up.
IF EXIST %Commands% DEL %Commands%

ENDLOCAL
```