# How to get findstr to filter for "last modified" files?

Tags: batch-file, subdirectory, findstr

I am looking to capture the Project Version in a set of files stored in folder and All sub-folders.

Using:

```
@echo off<br>
findstr /s "ProjectVersion" C:\srm2\reg\*.cpf > C:\RESULTS.txt
```

Returns every .cpf file in the folders.

e.g.

> ```
> C:\srm2\reg\132L\132L-20151111-150804.cpf:  <ProjectVersion Major="8" Minor="0" Build="22" Revision="20312" />
> C:\srm2\reg\132L\132L.cpf:  <ProjectVersion Major="11" Minor="0" Build="0" Revision="20312" />
> C:\srm2\reg\132L\132L18122014121012.cpf:  <ProjectVersion Major="8" Minor="0" Build="22" Revision="20312" />
> C:\srm2\reg\132L\132L18122014121731.cpf:  <ProjectVersion Major="8" Minor="0" Build="22" Revision="20312" />
> C:\srm2\reg\DANNY\DANNY-20151112-134545.cpf:  <ProjectVersion Major="11" Minor="0" Build="0" Revision="0" />
> C:\srm2\reg\DANNY\DANNY-20151113-083530.cpf:  <ProjectVersion Major="11" Minor="0" Build="0" Revision="0" />
> C:\srm2\reg\DANNY\DANNY-20151113-085621.cpf:  <ProjectVersion Major="11" Minor="0" Build="0" Revision="0" />
> C:\srm2\reg\DANNY\DANNY-20151113-102018.cpf:  <ProjectVersion Major="11" Minor="0" Build="0" Revision="0" />
> C:\srm2\reg\DANNY\DANNY.cpf:  <ProjectVersion Major="11" Minor="0" Build="0" Revision="0" />
> ```

How can I filter to return only the **last modified `.cpf` file in every sub-folder**, as some folders have many versions of the same file?

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried so far by editing your post!

Answer (score 1):

I copied the answer at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397674/windows-batch-file-looping-through-directories-to-process-files/8398621#8398621), that indicate: *"You may write a recursive algorithm in Batch that gives you exact control of what you do in every nested subdirectory"*, and slightly modified it in order to solve this problem. The approach is the same than other answers: walk through the tree and in each sub-folder execute `findstr` with just the first file ordered by last modified date; the difference is that this process is *explicitly* achieved via code, not via `for /R` or `dir /S` commands.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd C:\srm2\reg
call :treeProcess > C:\RESULTS.txt
goto :EOF


:treeProcess
set "output="
for /F "delims=" %%f in ('dir /B /A:-D /O:D *.cpf') do if not defined output (
   for /F "delims=" %%o in ('findstr "ProjectVersion" "%%f"') do set "output=!cd!\%%f: %%o"
)
if defined output echo !output!

rem Recursive call
for /D %%d in (*) do (
    cd %%d
    call :treeProcess
    cd ..
)

exit /b
```

Comment: Great approach, @Aacini, +1! what about performance of such recursive calls?

Comment: Works on server, but does spit out ECHO is off a lot  :)

Comment: @Mick: This happen when one sub-folder does _not_ have any `*.cpf` file! Just add `if defined output` before `echo !output!` in the code. I already did this in the answer...

Comment: @Aacini Thanks for the code and explanations. I wasn't complaining about the ECHO, apologies in advance. You guys on the forums are such valuable information stations to minions like myself.

Comment: @aschipfl: Well, the same than any other code with `call`'s! However, in this case the `call` is performed in each sub-folder level, so it may be more efficient than other code that do a `call` on each file.

Comment: @Aacini, I think the number of `call`s is even more in your code than in [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33695640/5047996), because I do it only once per each sub-directory that contains at least one file that matches the given pattern `*.cpf`, but you do it for _every_ sub-directory; that was mainly in my mind when asking about the performance, not knowing how many directories to _not_ contain any `*.cpf` file...

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "lastdir="
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('DIR /s /b /a-d /o-d "%sourcedir%\*.bat" ') DO IF "!lastdir!" neq "%%~dpa" (
 FINDSTR /i "z" "%%a" >NUL
 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  ECHO(%%a
  SET "lastdir=%%~dpa"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The one line of code you provide does not work at all.

This procedure simply produces a directory list of `*.bat` files in basic form (full-filename only) but sorted in reverse-date order and excluding directorynames.

The report is in reverse-date/time order within each directoryname, so the first matching filename for any directory is the latest file.

If the directory-name has changed, then execute a `findstr` to locate the required keystring. If it's found, `errorlevel` is set to `0`, hence it is not `1 or greater` so the filename is echoed and `lastdir` is set to the file's directoryname.

I simply used `*.bat` files and searched for `"z"` witin those files for testing. Adjust as required.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `for /R /D` to recursively walk through all directories, then use `dir /B /A:-D /O:-D` to return a list of files sorted per date (newest first) and parse its output by `for /F` taking only the first item, so you enumerate only the one newest file in every directory:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
> "C:\results.txt" (
    for /D /R %%D in ("C:\srm2\reg\*.*") do (
        call :SUB FILE LINE "%%~fD\*.cpf" "ProjectVersion"
        if defined LINE (
            echo/!FILE!:!LINE!
        )
    )
)
endlocal
exit /B

:SUB var_file var_line pattern string
set "%~1=" & set "%~2="
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%F in ('dir /B /A:-D /O:-D "%~3"') do (
    set "%~1=%%~fF"
    for /F "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /L "%~4" "%%~fF"') do (
        set "%~2=%%L"
        goto :EOF
    )
    goto :EOF
)
```

Let us take a look at the subroutine `:SUB` first, which is intended to execute once per each directory. This requires 4 parameters:

- (`%~1`) name of variable to hold the path to the retrieved file,
- (`%~2`) name of variable to hold the line that matches the search string,
- (`%~3`) the pattern to get a sorted list of files (newest first), and
- (`%~4`) the search string (expected to occur at most once per file).

The outer `for /F` loop parses the output of the command `dir /B /A:-D /O:-D "%~3"`, which actually builds the sorted list of files. The loop wants to iterate through every single line, but since there is a `goto :EOF` at the end, the loop is broken after the first iteration, so only the first (and therefore the newest) list item is processed. The path to this item is assigned to the first variable given as an argument. If no items match the file pattern, the variable remains empty.

The inner `for /F` loop parses the output of the search command `findstr`. Since only one occurrence of the search string is expected at most, this loop should iterate once only at most. If a match is found, the containing line is assigned to the second variable given as an argument. If no match is found, the variable remains empty.

Now let us check out the main routine. This walks through the given directory tree recursively using `for /D /R` and iterates through all directories. For each one, the subroutine `:SUB` is called, passing over the following arguments:

- variable name `FILE` (will receive the newest file in the currently itereted directory),
- variable name `LINE` (will receive the line in the file that matches the search string),
- the currently iterated directory with the file pattern `reg*.cpf` appended, and
- the demanded search string `ProjectVersion`.

Finally, the variable `LINE` is checked against emptiness, and if not, a line containing the file path, a colon and the found line is output by `echo`.

Notice that all output is redirected into file `C:\results.txt`.

This approach using a subroutine has been chosen, because there is a `goto` command used to terminate one certain `for` loop upon its first iteration (see description above), but not all of them. `goto` actually breaks all block contexts it is placed in, even all nested ones. `for` loops are just a kind of block command, like `if` clauses, or also simple grouped commands `()`. Using a subroutine prevents blocks of the main routine from being broken by a `goto` placed in the subroutine.

Comment: I did a small rework as I did not see the backslash between `reg` and `*.cpf`, so I treated `reg` as part of the file name rather than a directory; however, the functional code remains the same...