# Deleting a folder that contains large amount of files and showing the files that are being deleted

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, delete-file, windows-server-2012

I am deleting a folder that contains large amount of files (Milions of files) under Windows Server 2012 and i am using this command for this purpose :

```
rmdir /s/q foldername
```

Is there a way i can see the files that are being deleted in the cmd window?

Comment: It might help if you explain WHY you would want to see this? I can't imagine anyone sitting around watching millions of files being deleted.

Comment: You should probably look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397674/windows-batch-file-looping-through-directories-to-process-files. Instead of `rm`ing the whole directory, go through and for each file, `echo` it and then delete it. That's how I would do it.

Comment: @AsheraH because for some reason there are other programs running in parallele and adding content to my folder, so i wanna have an idea about this process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `DEL` to delete the files and `RMDIR` to delete the directories afterwards, you get your desired behaviour:

```
DEL /Q /S foldername\* && RMDIR /Q /S foldername
```