# Iterate through sub folders in windows command prompt matching a pattern and execute some commands in each folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a logic that I need to implement in a directory containing multiple sub-directories and files. Basically I want to execute the same set of commands in some specific sub-directories (name starting with letter 'x'). So far I have tried this in a `.bat` file.

```
for /r %%a in (x*) do (
  pushd %%a
    [some command]
  popd 
)
```

This bat file doesn't run. What am I missing? I tried to refer other similar questions but they did not help either

Comment: `Cmdlet`'s are `PowerShell` not `batch files`. You're missing reading the help information for your command. When you read the output returned from `For /?` you should see a `/D` option.

Comment: @Compo edited the question

Comment: Your edit does not take account of all of my advice, once that has been done, and your question edited accordingly, you may receive further help.

Comment: I suggest you to see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397674/windows-batch-file-looping-through-directories-to-process-files/8398621#8398621).